# How to store values with the special characters into HTML hidden fields using PHP

Tags: php

This may be a quite simple question but I can't figure it out. I need to store some value that contains special characters into HTML hidden fields using PHP such as `5' 5''` indicating the height of a person.

The value is stored into MySql database. I tried something like this

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='ed_your_height' name='hd_your_height' 
value=".html_entity_decode($your_heigth)."/>";
```

and

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='ed_your_height' name='hd_your_height' 
value=".htmlentities($your_heigth)."/>";
```

but it gives me the value `5'` instead of `5' 5''` in both the cases. I need to display these values in drop down and perform some comparisons.

How can I store values with the special characters into HTML hidden field then (retrieving from database)?

Comment: What does `var_dump($your_height);` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlentities()` and `html_entity_decode()` with the proper flags.

On the client-side

```
<input type="text name="fieldname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); ?>">
```

On the server-side:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($_POST['fieldname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
value="<?=htmlspecialchars($string)?>"
```

Assuming short_open_tag is on (bad) or you are using PHP 5.4 (good). Otherwise, use the full `<?php echo` form.

PS: The reason you were having a problem in the first place is because you were not quoting your attributes - if you used the browser's View Source option you'd see the output is `value=5' 5''` so it is interpreted as a value of `'5` and a custom boolean attribute called `5''`.